# How to use lua with python on Mac OS Mountain Lion

Tags: python, lua, osx-mountain-lion

I have been using Lupa 0.20 + LuaJIT 2.0.0 for embedding lua on python 2.7 code in a W7 box.  Unfortunately, I could not make it work on Mountain Lion Mac OS.  I am able to compile LuaJIT and Lupa, but whenever I try to use lupa, I get errors like:

```
lupa._lupa.LuaError: Failed to initialise Lua runtime
File "/Users/rafael/Projects/Lua/test.py", line 3, in <module>
lua = LuaRuntime()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lupa/_lupa.so", line 116, in     lupa._lupa.LuaRuntime.__cinit__ (lupa/_lupa.c:2237)
```

Is there any tip for making it work?

Comment: What do you mean by "embedding lua on python 2.7"?

Comment: I would like to use lua scripts from python scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use lupa x86_64 with the system-installed python. luajit 64-bit requires the executable (in this case, python) to have been linked with -pagezero_size 10000 -image_base 100000000.

The system-installed python was not linked that way, so your best bet is to figure out how to build a 32-bit luajit on osx (can't help there), build a 32-bit lupa (ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386" python setup.py build), and see if it works for you.

Or, build a 64-bit python that uses those linker flags.

EDIT: actually, lua51 works as a drop-in replacement for luajit.  Point the lupa setup.py at a lua51 distribution and library and build as usual; worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working on Mavericks, using a brew-installed Lua 5.1. Might work for you on Mountain Lion, too.

If you use the version from their git repo, the `setup.py` is already fixed and you can just download it, uncompress it, and install lupa by running:

`$ ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" python setup.py install --no-luajit`

If you'd rather use the released v0.20, just save those two files anywhere (but in the same directory) and run `make lupa clean`:

`lupa-5.1.diff`:

```
--- /Users/flavio/working_copies/databuild/lupa-0.20/setup.py 
+++ (clipboard) 
@@ -77,6 +77,7 @@
 basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

 def find_luajit_build():
+    return dict(libraries=['lua'], include_dirs=['/usr/local/include'])
     os_path = os.path
     for filename in os.listdir(basedir):
         if filename.lower().startswith('luajit'):
```

`Makefile`:

```
clean:
    rm -rf lupa-0.20*

lupa:
    brew install lua
    wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/l/lupa/lupa-0.20.tar.gz
    tar zxf lupa-0.20.tar.gz
    patch -p1 < lupa5.1.diff
    cd lupa-0.20/ && python setup.py install --no-luajit

test:
    ipython -c "from lupa import LuaRuntime; lua = LuaRuntime()"
```

Answer (score 0):

This came very close to working for me but fell slightly short.  A new version of lupa was released recently, so perhaps something changed.  For me, the above almost worked, but I got an issue with undefined symbols in the lua runtime.

I got Lupa to work on Mavericks doing the following:

- Install Lua on Homebrew: http://brew.sh/.
- Install cython:  For me I just used easy_install cython since I'm lazy and don't plan to use cython for anything other then making this work.  You could use homebrew for this too I imagine.
- Download / Install lupa:  Then, follow the instructions above, *except*, you need to also return None as a second parameter.  e.g.

  def find_lua_build(no_luajit=False):
      # try to find local LuaJIT2 build
      os_path = os.path 
      +return dict(libraries=['lua'], include_dirs=['/usr/local/include']), **None**
- Lastly, install the python module, and indicate explicitly to compile with cython:
  sudo python setup.py install --with-cython

If that doesn't work I would try playing around with different versions of lua in homebrew.  If you're wondering why the setup.py above is pointing at `/usr/local/include` that's where homebrew makes its symlinks to the active 'brew'.